# show a matrix is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

X is a complex inner product space.  A $\in$ L$_{\mathbb{C}}$(X,X) such that AA$^*$ = A$^2$. show that A is self-adjoint.  (i.e. A = A$^*$)

Through some process, I reach a result that A$^2$= (A*)$^2$. But I do not think I can conclude A = A* from it. Any help?

Comment: 1) Use MathJax please 2) Show us your elaborative attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not sure if any of my arguments fail in infinite-dimensional spaces...

Taking the conjugate of $AA^* = A^2$ yields $A^2 = AA^* = (A^*)^2$. Thus
$$(AA^*)^2 = (AA)^2 =  AAAA = AA A^* A = A^* A^* A^* A = A^* A A^* A = (A^* A)^2.$$
Because $(AA^*)^2$ and $(A^*A)^2$ are nonnegative definite, they have unique nonnegative definite square roots, so we obtain $AA^* = A^* A$, i.e. $A$ is normal.

The spectral theorem implies the existence of the decomposition $A=UDU^*$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal. Note that $UDDU^* = A^2 = AA^* = UDD^* U^*$ and thus $DD=DD^*$ and thus $D$ has real entries ($D=D^*$). Thus, $$A^* = U D^* U^* = UDU^* = A.$$